# Scala XML transformation with Rewrite rules

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I have a XML template with some fields predefined in it. I want to build new XML based on it template with new `Value` values using `RewriteRules`.

ex. 
template:

```
val template = <xml>
  <Persons>
    <Name>Persons</Name>
    <Person>
      <FullName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value></Value>
      </FullName>
      <LastName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value></Value>
      </LastName>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
</xml>

case class Person(fullName: String, lastName: String)
val persons = Seq(Person("John Smith", "Smith"), Person("Bob Saver", "Saver"))
```

output should be:

```
<xml>
  <Persons>
    <Name>Persons</Name>
    <Person>
      <FullName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value>John Smith</Value>
      </FullName>
      <LastName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value>Smith</Value>
      </LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <FullName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value>Bob Saver</Value>
      </FullName>
      <LastName>
        <Name>Name of the field</Name>
        <Value>Saver</Value>
      </LastName>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
</xml>
```

Is it possible to do with `RewriteRules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `RewriteRules` for this purposes. You can define variables in your xml template.

```
scala> def template(id: String = "defaultValue can be here") = <someXml>{id}</someXml>
template: (id: String)scala.xml.Elem

scala> template("person")
res4: scala.xml.Elem = <someXml>person</someXml>
scala> template("person2")
res5: scala.xml.Elem = <someXml>person2</someXml>
```

otherwise
[Scala - replace xml element with specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705693/scala-replace-xml-element-with-specific-text)